# Finding number of components in Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given an array $A$ having $N$ elements. Consider an undirected graph $G$ with $N$ vertices. There is an edge between two vertices $i$ and $j$ if and only if $A_i$ and $A_j$ are coprime. I am required to find number of connected components in graph $G$.

I tried a brute force approach to solve this problem. For each pair of elements in $A$, if their GCD is $1$, then I add an edge between them and finally use Depth First Search to find number of components. But this approach is $O(n^{2}\log(n))$. Is there any way I can do it in better say, $O(n\log(n))$ ?

Comment: If the problem comes from a contest, **state so explicitly**.

Comment: I'm satisfied that you've thought sufficiently about the problem to appreciate what an Answer will consist of.  However the problem statement is ambiguous as to whether the computation of edges (coprimality) is part of the requirement.  One might interpret the Question as providing us with undirected graph $G$ whose edges happen to be assigned according to the described relation.  As you've pointed out in the Comments on the nice Answer by @lesnik, we have no way to bound the computational effort in checking whether $A_i$ and $A_j$ are coprime in terms of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe it's possible to achieve $O(n*log(n))$. Suppose all the numbers in a given set are co-prime. You will have to check all pairs to make sure they are co-prime. Although I can't prove it.

But you can get better than $O(n^2 * log(n))$.

Check out [Disjoined set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

Using this approach you can get the connected components at $O(\alpha(n^2))$, where $\alpha$ is an inverse Ackermann function. It grows slightly faster than linear, but the difference is ridiculously small.

The algorithm uses couple of clever tricks, but looks approximately like this.

Each node in the graph remembers it's "parent", the parent and the node belong to the same connected component. In the beginning each node's parent is the node itself and we have $n$ components. Than we add edges one by one and update this "child-parent" structure. In the end each node's parent would be a representative of the component. So that two nodes belong to the same component iff their parents are the same.

After that you only need to sort the array by the value of parent ($O(n*log(n))$) and calculate the number of different parents ($O(n)$). So the total complexity is $O(\alpha(n^2))$.

Comment: I know about Disjoined set data structure. My complexity turns out to be O(n^2log(n)) since i use two loops and in inner loop i check if their gcd is 1 or not, time complexity of gcd(a, b) is log(min(a, b)). Hence, it turns out to be O(n^2log(n)). My doubt is to reduce one n from final time complexity, so to have O(nlog(n)) or O(nlog^2(n))...

Comment: @J.Jack Sorry, I don't quite understand you. Could you please clarify?
We have $N$ - number of elements in the array. That's ok.
Than we have $n$. What is this?
My guess was that $n$ is a total size of the problem. It's different from $N$ because the elements of array may be large. But then complexity of gcd(a, b) is log(min(a, b)) = min(size(a), size(b)). Where log(n) comes from?

Comment: sorry, i was using `n` and `N` interchangeably.

Comment: @J.Jack Ok, I see. But in this case the complexity of calculation of gcd(a, b) should not depend on $N$. Total number of elements in array should not affect calculation of gcd of two of them, shouldn't it?